# Trouble setting scriptSrc attribute in Lucee CFForm

Tags: tomcat, cfml, lucee

I'm trying to move a web app from ColdFusion to Lucee, and I'm having trouble getting CFForms to work properly.

The directory structure for my project is: `C:\lucee\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\appname\Templates\JavaScripts`,
where Templates is the directory with my .cfm files. I'm trying to set the scriptSrc attribute of a cfform to point to the JavaScripts directory, but I keep getting a 404 error when the page loads:

```
<cfform name        = "OfferCreateForm"
            action  = "OfferCreate_Processing.cfm"
            method  = "post"
            onSubmit    = "return(ClientSideValidation() && DoubleSubmissionCheck());"
            scriptSrc= "./JavaScripts">


GET http://127.0.0.1:8888/appname/Templates/JavaScripts/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

(I've tried a bunch of different things with the scriptSrc such as removing the leading period and slash, specifying the entire path to the directory, etc. with no luck)

When I try to access the files in that directory directly, they will only load if I don't have a trailing slash at the end, which I'm guessing is part of what's going on here. However, I know almost nothing about Lucee or Tomcat so I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What is the version of Lucee & form extension, you're using?

Comment: I'm using Lucee 5.3.8.201. I was able to fix the issue for a while yesterday by giving the path to form.cfm in the scriptSrc attribute, but now when I go to that page today the error is happening again.

Comment: Tried to edit the above comment but I'm too late - I am able to get rid of that error now when I set the scriptSrc to JavaScripts/form.cfm. The documentation for cfform says that the scriptSrc attribute is looking for a directory though, not a file, so that is pretty weird.

Comment: Yes, scriptSrc should be pointing to a directory which have cfform.js etc.. I'm not sure why & where you're getting error.. If you're manually entering the URL (http://127.0.0.1:8888/appname/Templates/JavaScripts/ ) on browser, Then It is a misunderstanding.. scriptSrc is just for adding additional javascripts to be loaded to make the cfform working properly.. I hope you're not try loading on browser..

Comment: I'm getting that error on the line that has the scriptSrc attribute set. I just entered the JavaScripts directory URL through the browser to make sure that it could be accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this was to put the path to form.cfm itself in the scriptSrc attribute, not the path for the directory that contains form.cfm.

```
<cfform name        = "OfferCreateForm"
        action  = "OfferCreate_Processing.cfm"
        method  = "post"
        onSubmit    = "return(ClientSideValidation() && DoubleSubmissionCheck());"
        scriptSrc= "./JavaScripts/form.cfm">
```